# DrawerLayout: How to make this Custom Layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to make these in a DrawerLayout but unable to find the right approach.

**WANT THESE LAYOUTS**
[image]

and

[image]

I have tried and been thinking about this. Should I use

1 - List

Problem: How to add separator and group things.

2 - List + Grid

3 - TableView

I am posting code below. I am not experienced and don't think its the right approach. Give me some directions Please.

**CODE**

```
        <ListView.Header>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="bg.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                    <StackLayout Padding="11,110,0,20" >
                        <Label  Text="AppName" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium"  Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Header>

        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="All Tasks" IconSource="ic_date_range_black_48dp.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ContactsPage}" Color="Black" />
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="Today" IconSource="ic_date_range_black_48dp.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:TodoListPage}" Color="Black"/>
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="Completed" IconSource="ic_check_black_48dp.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ReminderPage}" Color="Green"/>
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="InComplete" IconSource="ic_close_black_48dp.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ReminderPage}" Color="Red"/>
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="My List" IconSource="ic_date_range_black_48dp.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ReminderPage}" Color="Black"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="5" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>


    </ListView>

    <BoxView VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="1" Color="#5b5d68"></BoxView>

    <Grid Padding="5,10" BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="ic_date_range_black_48dp.png" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Create List" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="ic_date_range_black_48dp.png" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Settings" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

**RESULT**
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the ItemsSource of listview in code.
For example:

```
    public ListView ListView;
    public MasterPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListView = ItemListview;
        List<List<MasterPageItem>> masterPageItemGroup = new List<List<MasterPageItem>>(){
        new List<MasterPageItem>(){
            new MasterPageItem() { Title = "All Tasks", IconSource = "ic_date_range_black_48dp.png", Color = "Black" }
        },
        new List<MasterPageItem>(){
             new MasterPageItem() { Title="Today", IconSource="ic_date_range_black_48dp.png",  Color="Black" },
              new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Completed", IconSource = "ic_check_black_48dp.png", Color = "Green" },
               new MasterPageItem() { Title = "InComplete", IconSource = "ic_close_black_48dp.png", Color = "Red" },
        },
        new List<MasterPageItem>(){
            new MasterPageItem() { Title="My List", IconSource="ic_date_range_black_48dp.png" , Color="Black" }
        },
        };
        ListView.ItemsSource = masterPageItemGroup;
    }
```

Then set `IsGroupingEnabled` value to `true` in xaml. And if you want to hide  group header, you also need to set `HasUnevenRows` to `true` and use the `ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate`. In the `GroupHeaderTemplate` create a `ViewCell` and set `Height` to 0.
Here is the xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemListview" IsGroupingEnabled="true" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.Header>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="bg.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                <StackLayout Padding="11,110,0,20" >
                    <Label  Text="AppName" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium"  Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ListView.Header>         
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="5,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="5" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="0">
                <Grid/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The result is:
[image]

**Update:**

> How can I remove/hide line above All Tasks?. This shouldn't be there.

It seems that it could not be removed. But the is a workaround. If you remove the `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` in your `ListView.Header`, the line will be hidden by bg.jpg.
The result:
[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Let me test this and I get back to you.

Comment: @Pirzada Is there any problem?

Comment: How can I remove/hide line above All Tasks?. This shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Pirzada Sorry for the late response. I have updated my answer, please check it.